# Python Script doesn't work in conda environment but in iPython

Tags: python, kernel, conda

I am working on a `python` script for a `sparse PCA`.
I am using `Anaconda 4.3.1` and `Python 3.6.1.`

The script I am working on works well in `iPython` in my environment. But if I start it directly in the `terminal`, while I'm in my environment it doesn't run and I get the error from pandas:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd'
```

If I run the script outside the environment it works well.
How could that be?

Comment: "while I'm in my environment" - are you positive about that? Have you activated the enrionment? is `sys.path` in IPython the same as the output of `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`?

Comment: IPython is referring to the path /anaconda/lib/ and the output in the terminal is referring to /anaconda/envs/firstenv/lib/
But I activated my environment first and then started IPython

Comment: You have to install IPython into that environment as well. Right now, it is running the IPython installed in your root environment.